# How to join large number of tabs in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

- All sheets are labelled "dn1,dn2...dn100"
- Only need the first 4 columns of each sheet

```
=query({dn1!A1:D;dn2!A1:D;...}
```

Comment: I can show you how to do this without needing to enter the sheetnames one at a time.  It can be done without Google Appscript.  If you share an editable sample sheet with an accurate representation of the real data, it can be better understood and demonstrated there as well as answered here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the sheet names one by one, dn1 until dn100.

```
=query({dn1!A1:D;dn2!A1:D;...;dn100!A1:D},...)
```

Comment: Thats so bad, is there really no faster way